# exclude row by maping id and fetch records by mapping name in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Guys help me out mongodb query that I want write that.

skip the row by `id` and find by `name` matching row. I put my query below suggest me the right way

`db.college.find({"_id" : {$ne: ObjectId("5b965696b8bba46518cbefda")}},{ $and:[{ "Name" : "KK" }]})`

here am getting all rows of records. but I want to get only matching recor

Answer (score 1):

Both conditions should be in one object like this:

```
db.college.find({"_id" : { $ne: ObjectId("5b965696b8bba46518cbefda")}, "Name": "KK" })
```

Second parameter of `find` represents [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)